# CoreData FetchRequest is loading my List with Optional result data in addition to the FetchedData

Tags: core-data, swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm calling a @FetchRequest inside of the AdminView struct, where I wish to present the data inside of a List using a ForEach. I'm Requesting all User entity data but when I run the app, the list shows my 2 existing entry results but it also shows about 40 entries that default to the Optional String "TEST" for some reason.

I'm trying to understand how I can get the List to only show the two User Entries without showing the default String in the list.

Much appreciated!

Here is the relevant code:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData


extension User {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<User> {
        return NSFetchRequest<User>(entityName: "User")
    }

    @NSManaged public var admin: Bool
    @NSManaged public var company: String?
    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var password: String?
    @NSManaged public var photo: Data?
    @NSManaged public var username: String?
    @NSManaged public var id: UUID?
    @NSManaged public var tickets: NSSet?

}

// MARK: Generated accessors for tickets
extension User {

    @objc(addTicketsObject:)
    @NSManaged public func addToTickets(_ value: Ticket)

    @objc(removeTicketsObject:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromTickets(_ value: Ticket)

    @objc(addTickets:)
    @NSManaged public func addToTickets(_ values: NSSet)

    @objc(removeTickets:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromTickets(_ values: NSSet)

}

extension User : Identifiable {

}

extension User {
    static func getAllUsers() -> NSFetchRequest<User> {
        let request:NSFetchRequest<User> = User.fetchRequest()

        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \User.company, ascending: false)
        request.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

        return request
    }
}





import SwiftUI

struct AdminView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @EnvironmentObject var goToContentView: moveToContentView
    @ObservedObject var selectedUser : User
    @State var selectedImageArray : [UIImage]
    
    @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: User.getAllUsers()) var allUsers:FetchedResults<User>

    var body: some View {
        List{
            ForEach(self.allUsers) { user in
                VStack{
                    Text(user.company ?? "TEST")
                }
            }
     }
        .toolbar(content: {
            EditButton()
        })
        .animation(.default)
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .navigationTitle("ADMIN")
        .navigationBarItems(leading: Button(action: {
            
            if self.goToContentView.goToViewFromLogin == true {
                self.goToContentView.goToViewFromLogin = false
            } else {
                self.goToContentView.goToViewFromRegister = false
            }
            
        }) {
            HStack {
                Text("Sign Out")
            }
        },trailing: HStack{
            Image(systemName: "bell")
                .font(.system(size: 30))
            Image(uiImage: selectedImageArray.first!)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            Text(selectedUser.name!)
                .font(.system(size: 20))
        })
        
    }
}
```

Comment: sounds like you may have inadvertently added a load of blank entries into your core data database. Could that possibly have happened? Might be worth deleting your app from your simulator or phone (depending on where you are running it), rebuilding and then re-adding the two user records to see if you get the same behaviour. I can also talk you through how you can view the actual database using an SQLViewer if you like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a filter to the list. You can also use let instead of the nil-coalescing operator. No need for the VStack since the Text will all be inside the list.

```
List {
   ForEach(self.allUsers.filter({ $0.company != nil })) { user in
      if let company = user.company {
          Text(company)
      }
   }
}
```